# Ошибка в градиентах при создании стикера телеграм TGS

Tags: telegram, after-effects

Я импортировал графику из Illustrator в After Effects черед плагин Battle Axe Overload. Вся графика, как видите, в кривых:

[image]

Затем я ипользовал Bodymovin-TG чтобы отрендерить TGS стикеры для телеграма. Когда я загружаю их боту @Stickers, все градиенты становятся черно-белыми.

Как это выглядит в AE:
[image]

Так после экспорта в телеграм:
[image]

Есть способ это исправить? "Allow Scripts to Write Files and Access Network" нажато.

Answer (score 0):

уже не в первый раз задаюсь этим вопросом, и попадаю на эту страницу:) каждый раз мне почему-то помогают разные действия, первое - это вручную заново создать градиент, те удаляем градиент и заливку, через add, добавляем Fill, важно перед этим проверить чтобы у заливки стояла именно равномерная заливка в настройках, вот уже после добавления равномерного fill, меняем сверху на градиент, какой нужен. Еще находила рекомендации сохранять проект перед выводом и переименовывать группы к которым привязываются градиенты, чтобы не было одинаковых названий.